# Logged in user groups

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory

I have Angular app that uses Azure AD authentication. Its implemented using AdalService. Logging in works fine and from app basic user info can be accessed. But to access user groups there has to be made a GET call to 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf'.

The problem is, my user does not have permissions to make request 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf' and it is currently not possible to change permissions. Are there any other ways to access logged in user groups?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some confusion in regards to the issue here.

The problem is that your Access token doesn't have the right permissions and this needs to be requested at the time of getting the access token.

Please see the Microsoft Graph API for memberof here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

To make this call depending on the type of token you're trying to use (Application/Delegated Permission)

Permission type Permissions (from least to most privileged)
Delegated (work or school account)  Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All
Delegated (personal Microsoft account)  Not supported.
Application Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All

Please refer to the tutorials/docs on how to do this. 
It looks like you're interested in using the Auth Code flow, please note that there are many different flows that get different access tokens. Refer to the docs for more information on this : 
Also please note that there are two AAD Endpoints as well, the v1.0 and v2.0 endpoints.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios - Auth Basics

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow - Client Credentials v2.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow - Client Credentials V1.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison - Comparison of V1 and v2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-permissions-and-consent - Permissions and Consent v1.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent - Permissions and Consent v2.0